# TFX - What is example_gen_pb2 and where is it documented?

Tags: tfx

[The ExampleGen TFX Pipeline Component](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/examplegen) has the example code which uses **example_gen_pb2** but what is it and where is it documented?

```
# Input has a single split 'input_dir/*'.
# Output 2 splits: train:eval=3:1.
output = proto.Output(
             split_config=example_gen_pb2.SplitConfig(splits=[
                 proto.SplitConfig.Split(name='train', hash_buckets=3),
                 proto.SplitConfig.Split(name='eval', hash_buckets=1)
             ]))
example_gen = CsvExampleGen(input_base=input_dir, output_config=output)
```

Answer (score 0):

The API doc is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/api_docs/python/tfx/v1/proto).
Since it's proto file, the easiest way is checking the [definition](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/blob/master/tfx/proto/example_gen.proto) itself, which has comments for the data structure.
Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to import it, you can do it from tfx.proto:

```
from tfx.proto import example_gen_pb2
```

Source:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/blob/master/tfx/components/example_gen/utils_test.py